"I get holes in my jeans......" | "My jeans get holed in ........." | "My jeans get holes......."
A native english speaker is talking about his clothes. He says:
You can never have too many pairs of jeans, can you? because you know after a while, the jeans all chafe under here, and I end up getting holes in them.
The structure "I get holes..." sounded funny to me as a non-native speaker, maybe because objects get holes in my language, not humans. Anyway, I don't know if it is the only way to say it idiomatically. So, I have two questions about this aspect of English:
1- Why is it "...I get holes in them" whereas it is the jeans that gets the holes.? Is this the only structure to use when other things such as shoes/socks/ get holes in them? In other words, to sound natural, are we supposed to say "I get holes in my shoes in 6 months" instead of "My shoes get holes in 6 months."
2- Considering "to hole" is a verb; instead of "I get holes...", can we say "The jeans get holed in 6 months" like making passive sentences such as "The machine gets cleaned automatically"?

"i get holes in them" is no different to "I get dirt on them" or "I get stains on them". I doubt your native language has an exact equivalent of get used in every context English get is.

"hole" in this context is not a verb.

I don't have any evidence, but for me the use of "hole" as a verb implies a singular event that made a hole, eg in a boat. Here you're talking about holes forming over months due to wear and tear, so I wouldn't say the verb was appropriate.

@DanielRoseman See the discussion I'm having with FumbleFingers in comments below. I've never encountered such a transitive verb in American English that would apply to holes in clothing that have occurred as the result of much wear.

Would you accept "I got a pebble in my shoe" as an alternative to "My shoe has got a pebble in it"?  The former sentence is a natural way of expressing the fact.  The shoe has a pebble, but you have the shoe and it is normal and idiomatic to say "I got a pebble".
There is really no difference with "hole"  The word "hole" is being used as a noun and you can have a hole just as you can have a pebble. The jeans have a hole, but you have the jeans, so you have a hole.
The use of "got" is common too, especially when talking about a change of state (I got hurt, got married, got an "A" ...).  You can use both "I got holes" or "My jeans got holes"
The verb form is not impossible, but unlikely when talking about clothes.  The verb form "to hole" is normally used with boats or other craft, not jeans.

Thanks I understand it better now, however, I wonder whether "to get"in the sentence "I got a pebble in my shoe", is the verb "to get" or is it the shortned form of the structure "have got"? In other words, when you say "I got a pebble in imy shoe", are you using the shortened form of "I have got a pebble in my shoe"?

@Yunus - In these constructions, consider "get" as a synonym of "acquire". Saying "I have a pebble in my shoe," just says that the pebble is there. Saying "I got a pebble in my shoe," draws attention to the fact that you initially had no pebble, but at some point, the pebble was acquired.


I get holes in my shoes in six months.

This sounds fine.  Such constructions are common, and I would more likely say I have ten dollars in my wallet than my wallet has ten dollars.
(Your proposed "My shoes get holes in six months" is understood too.)
Using the passive holed is valid;  I paste here a sample from ldoceonline.com:

be holed
• In spite of this, no planes were lost to antiaircraft fire, although nearly half of them were holed.

I just find The jeans get holed to be less natural than  I get holes in my jeans.

There is no regularly used (i.e. non-jargon) transitive verb  with the meaning "to put a hole in something".

That is, no such verb (to hole something) with the meaning "to put holes in".

The full OED's first definition for the verb hole is I.1.a.: transitive. To hollow out; to make a hole or cavity in; to perforate, pierce. Where to my mind, to perforate strongly implies making multiple holes. Personally, I prefer My jeans get holes in them over I get holes in my jeans, but the choice is of no significance.

@FumbleFingers  When is the last time you encountered it in conversation that wasn't in a military context (pierced by bullets)?   Am I to understand from your citing that definition (which also appears in M-W) that this is perfectly idiomatic in BrE:   "I wore those jeans so much that they were holed."

@TimR: You certainly should not understand my comment to mean that I think "I wore those jeans so much that they were holed" is perfectly idiomatic, obviously! But I have no problem with the OED's most recent citation under that first definition: Some 80 miles of the route already holed [for telegraph posts]. No bullets there - not that it really makes any difference, but the specific example in this answer does imply "bulletholes", and that's certainly a common context for the usage.

Just to be clear, my question is, in England, do people actually say "My jeans are holed"?  The meanings in M-W and Oxford refer to holes intentionally made, either by enemy fire or some sort of equipment for making holes.  I ask because in all my years of wearing jeans and talking with people wearing jeans nobody has ever said "My jeans are holed" but "My jeans have holes in them".

Above, where I say "put" I should have added "by over-use", i.e. synonymous with "I've worn holes in these jeans."  I have never encountered a verb "to hole" having that meaning in any conversation about clothing or fabric, where holes occur as the result of wear and tear.
